# CKEdtior multiple editors same toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to find a neat way of having several CKEditors at the same page, but with only one toolbar.

I've achived this by:

HTML

```
<textarea id="editor1" class="editor"></textarea>
<br/>
<textarea id="editor2" class="editor"></textarea>
<br/>
<textarea id="editor3" class="editor"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.editor').each(function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace($(this).attr('id'), {
        extraPlugins: 'sharedspace',
        removePlugins: 'resize,elementspath',
        sharedSpaces: {
            top: 'toolbar'
            }
        });
    });
```

But hoping there would be a neater way of accomplishing it.

**EDIT: This worked out in the end.**

```
// update your config.js accordingly, feel free to add more settings if you like
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config){
    extraPlugins: 'sharedspace',
    removePlugins: 'resize,elementspath',
    sharedSpaces: {
       top: 'toolbar'
       }
    };

// this will transform your textareas will class "editor" to CKEditos
// the id attribute in the textarea element seems to be necessary.
CKEDITOR.replaceClass = 'editor';
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Each CKEditor instance comes with its own Toolbar which will update the element it is bound to. If you have 1 toolbar (which is impossible I think), how will the plugin know which textarea to manipulate? Unless I don't understand your question correctly?

Comment: Well, like I said. I have already managed that and it seem to work. I am just looking for a more elegant approach of achiving it.